# Why does styled-components 5.x warn about "Expected style to contain units."

Tags: react-native, styled-components

When styling a React Native app with Styled Components 5.x I'm getting the warning...

> Expected style "borderWidth: 2" to contain units.

[image: must contain units warning]

This didn't happen with previous versions.

What does the warning mean?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*<sub>After some research and questions on github I tracked this one down...</sub>*

Styled Components uses the package [css-to-react-native](https://github.com/styled-components/css-to-react-native) for it's React Native conversions.

css-to-react-native recently released version 3 which now requires units to be present for all measurements. [Details here](https://github.com/styled-components/css-to-react-native/issues/40).

You should use `px` for React Native as it is [density independent](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#px).

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `px` is a bit of a pain, unintuitive, misleading, and even dangerous if you are using a theme giving some `...px` string value to a component (`Ionicons` `size` for instance) that expect react native `number` units.

My way of dealing with this:

```js
import { LogBox } from 'react-native'

LogBox.ignoreLogs([`to contain units`])
```